# Deserializing JSON into Serializable class with generic field - error: Star projections in type arguments are not allowed

Tags: json, kotlin, serialization, kotlinx.serialization

### Intro

I'm sending JSON messages between two backend servers that use different languages. The producing
server creates a variety of JSON messages, wrapped inside a message with metadata.

The wrapping class is `Message`, The consuming server has to determine which type of message its
receiving based solely on the message contents.

When I try to use a [star-projection](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/generics.html#star-projections) to
deserialize the message, I get an error.

#### Example

```kotlin
import kotlinx.serialization.json.Json

@Language("JSON")
val carJson = """
    {
      "message_type": "some message",
      "data": {
        "info_type": "Car",
        "name": "Toyota"
      }
    }
  """.trimIndent()

// normally I wouldn't know what the Json message would be - so the type is Message<*>
val actualCarMessage = Json.decodeFromString<Message<*>>(carJson)
```

#### Error message

```sh
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Star projections in type arguments are not allowed, but Message<*>
    at kotlinx.serialization.SerializersKt__SerializersKt.serializerByKTypeImpl$SerializersKt__SerializersKt(Serializers.kt:81)
    at kotlinx.serialization.SerializersKt__SerializersKt.serializer(Serializers.kt:59)
    at kotlinx.serialization.SerializersKt.serializer(Unknown Source)
    at ExampleKt.main(example.kt:96)
    at ExampleKt.main(example.kt)
```

### Class structure

I want to deserialize JSON into a data class, `Message`, that has a field with a generic type.

```kotlin
import kotlinx.serialization.SerialName
import kotlinx.serialization.Serializable

@Serializable
data class Message<out DataType : SpecificInformation>(
  @SerialName("message_type")
  val type: String,
  @SerialName("data")
  val data: DataType,
)
```

The field is constrained by a sealed interface, `SpecificInformation`, with some implementations.

```kotlin
import kotlinx.serialization.SerialName
import kotlinx.serialization.Serializable
import kotlinx.serialization.json.JsonClassDiscriminator

@JsonClassDiscriminator("info_type")
sealed interface SpecificInformation {
  @SerialName("info_type")
  val infoType: String
}

@Serializable
@SerialName("User")
data class UserInformation(
  @SerialName("info_type")
  override val infoType: String,
  val name: String,
) : SpecificInformation

// there are more implementations...
```

### Workaround?

This is a known
issue ([kotlinx.serialization/issues/944](https://github.com/Kotlin/kotlinx.serialization/issues/944))
,
so I'm looking for workarounds.

I have control over the JSON structure and libraries - though I have a preference for
kotlinx.serialization.

I can't change that there are two JSON objects, one is inside the other, and the discriminator is
inside the inner-class.

A custom serializer would be great. But I'd prefer to have this configured on the class or file
(with `@Serializable(with = ...)` or `@file:UseSerializers(...)`) as using a
custom `SerializersModule` is not as seamless.

#### Attempt: `JsonContentPolymorphicSerializer`

I've written a custom serializer, which only if it's used specifically (which is something I'd like
to avoid). It's also quite clunky, breaks if the data classes change or a new one is added, and
doesn't benefit from the `sealed interface`.

Can this be improved so that

1. It can be used generically? `Json.decodeFromString<Message<*>>(carJson)`
2. It doesn't have any hard-coded strings?

```kotlin
class MessageCustomSerializer : JsonContentPolymorphicSerializer<Message<*>>(Message::class) {
  override fun selectDeserializer(element: JsonElement): DeserializationStrategy<out Message<*>> {

    val discriminator = element
      .jsonObject["data"]
      ?.jsonObject?.get("info_type")
      ?.jsonPrimitive?.contentOrNull
    println("found discriminator $discriminator")

    val subclassSerializer = when (discriminator?.lowercase()) {
      "user" -> UserInformation.serializer()
      "car"  -> CarInformation.serializer()
      else   -> throw IllegalStateException("could not find serializer for $discriminator")
    }
    println("found subclassSerializer $subclassSerializer")

    return Message.serializer(subclassSerializer)
  }
}

fun main() {

  @Language("JSON")
  val carJson = """
      {
        "message_type": "another message",
        "data": {
          "info_type": "Car",
          "brand": "Toyota"
        }
      }
    """.trimIndent()

  val actualCarMessage =
    Json.decodeFromString(MessageCustomSerializer(), carJson)
  val expectedCarMessage = Message("another message", CarInformation("Car", "Toyota"))

  require(actualCarMessage == expectedCarMessage) {
    println("car json parsing ❌")
  }
  println("car json parsing ✅")
}
```

##### `@Serializable(with = ...` - infinite loop

I tried applying `MessageCustomSerializer` directly to `Message`...

```kotlin
@Serializable(with = MessageCustomSerializer::class)
data class Message<out T : SpecificInformation>(
//...
```

But then I couldn't access the plugin-generated serializer, and this causes an infinite loop.

```kotlin
return Message.serializer(subclassSerializer) // calls 'MessageCustomSerializer', causes infinite loop
```

##### `@Serializer(forClass = ...)` - not generic

In addition to annotating `Message` with `@Serializable(with = MessageCustomSerializer::class)`, I
tried
deriving [a plugin-generated serializer](https://github.com/Kotlin/kotlinx.serialization/blob/471f4bbfa28d0dd1d4af869dc992d7604374e4ac/docs/serializers.md#deriving-external-serializer-for-another-kotlin-class-experimental):

```kotlin
@Serializer(forClass = Message::class)
object MessagePluginGeneratedSerializer : KSerializer<Message<*>>
```

But this serializer is not generic, and causes an error

```sh
java.lang.AssertionError: No such value argument slot in IrConstructorCallImpl: 0 (total=0).
Symbol: MessageCustomSerializer.<init>|-5645683436151566731[0]
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.ir.expressions.IrMemberAccessExpressionKt.throwNoSuchArgumentSlotException(IrMemberAccessExpression.kt:66)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.ir.expressions.IrFunctionAccessExpression.putValueArgument(IrFunctionAccessExpression.kt:31)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlinx.serialization.compiler.backend.ir.IrBuilderExtension$DefaultImpls.irInvoke(GeneratorHelpers.kt:210)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlinx.serialization.compiler.backend.ir.SerializableCompanionIrGenerator.irInvoke(SerializableCompanionIrGenerator.kt:35)
```

Answer (score 1):

You are asking many things here, so I will simply try to give some pointers in regards to the errors you are making which you seem to be stuck on. With those in mind, and reading the documentation I link to, I believe you should be able to resolve the rest yourself.

#### Polymorphic serialization

Acquaint yourself with `kotlinx.serialization` [polymorphic serialization](https://github.com/Kotlin/kotlinx.serialization/blob/master/docs/polymorphism.md). When you are trying to serialize `Message<*>` and `DataType` you are trying to use polymorphic serialization.

In case you are serializing `Message<*>` as the root object, specifying `PolymorphicSerializer` explicitly (as I also posted in [the bug report you link to](https://github.com/Kotlin/kotlinx.serialization/issues/944#issuecomment-832692723)) should work. E.g., `Json.decodeFromString( PolymorphicSerializer( Message::class ), carJson )`.

P.s. I'm not 100% certain what you are trying to do here is the same as in the bug report. Either way, specifying the serializer explicitely should work, whether or not it is a *bug* that you shouldn't be required to do so.

The `message_type` and `info_type` fields you have in `Message` and `DataType` respectively are [class discriminators](https://github.com/Kotlin/kotlinx.serialization/blob/master/docs/json.md#class-discriminator). You need to configure this in your Json settings, and set the correct `SerialName` on your concrete classes for them to work. Using a different class discriminator per hierarchy is only possible [starting from `kotlinx.serialization` 1.3.0](https://github.com/Kotlin/kotlinx.serialization/releases/tag/v1.3.0-RC) using [`@JsonClassDiscriminator`](https://kotlin.github.io/kotlinx.serialization/kotlinx-serialization-json/kotlinx-serialization-json/kotlinx.serialization.json/-json-class-discriminator/index.html).

#### Overriding plugin-generated serializer

> But then I couldn't access the plugin-generated serializer, and this causes an infinite loop.

`@Serializable(with = ...)` overrides the plugin-generated serializer. If you want to retain the plugin-generated serializer, do not apply `with`.

When you are serializing the object directly (as the root object), you can still pass a different serializer to use as the first parameter to `encode`/`decode`. When you want to override the serializer to use for a specific property nested somewhere in the root object, [use `@Serializable` on the property](https://github.com/Kotlin/kotlinx.serialization/blob/master/docs/serializers.md#specifying-serializer-on-a-property).

#### Polymorphism and generic classes

The *"No such value argument slot in IrConstructorCallImpl: 0"* error is to be expected.

You [need to do more work](https://github.com/Kotlin/kotlinx.serialization/blob/master/docs/polymorphism.md#polymorphism-and-generic-classes) in case you want to specify a serializer for polymorphic generic classes.